# Lazy rendering of Qt on OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt4, paint

i came about [this](http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=15904) problem and knew it could be done better.

### The problem:

When overlaying a QGLWidget (Qt OpenGL contextview) with Qt widgets, Qt redraws those widgets after every Qt frame.

Qt isn’t built to redraw entire windows with >60fps constantly, so that’s enormously slow.

### My idea:

Make Qt use something other to draw upon: a transparent texture. Make OpenGL use this texture whenever it redraws and draw it on top of everything else. Make Qt redirect all interaction with the OpenGL context view to the widgets drawn onto the texture.

The advantage would be that Qt only has to redraw whenever it has to (e.g. a widget is hovered or clicked, or the text cursor in a text field blinks), and can do partial redraws which are faster.

### My Question:

How to approach this? how can I tell Qt to draw to a texture? how can i redirect interaction with a widget to another one (e.g. if i move the mouse above the region in the context view where a checkbox sits in the drawn-to-texture widget, Qt should register this event to the checkbox and repaint to reflect itshovered state)

Comment: Are you drawing the OpenGL content faster than 60 fps?

Comment: then let’s say =60fps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I separate my 2D and 3D rendering out for my CAD-like app for the very same reasons you have, although in my case my the 2D stuff are not widgets - but it shouldn't make a difference.  This is how would approach the problem:

1. When your widget changes render it onto a `QGLFramebufferObject`, do this by using the FBO as the `QPaintDevice` for a `QPainter` in your `QGLWidget::paintEvent(..)` and calling `myWidget->render( myQPainter, ...)`.  Repeat this for however many widgets you have, but only onto the same FBO - don't create an FBO for each one... Remember to clear it first, like a 'normal' framebuffer.
2. When your current OpenGL background changes, render it onto another `QGLFramebufferObject` using standard OpenGL calls, in the same way.
3. Create a pass through vertex shader (the 'camera' will just be a unit cube), and a very simple fragment shader that can layer the two textures on top of each other.
4. At the end of the `QGLWidget::paintEvent(..)`, activate your shader program, bind your framebuffers as textures for it (`myFBO->texture()` gets the handle), and render a unit quad.  Because your camera is a unit square, and the viewport size defined the FBO size, it will fill the viewport pixel perfect.

However, that's the easy part...  The hard part is the widget interaction.  Because you are essentially rendering a 'proxy', you going to have to relay the interaction between the 'real' and 'proxy' widget, whilst keeping the 'real' widget invisible.  Here's how would I start:

- Some operating systems are a bit weird about rendering widgets without *ever* showing them, so you may have to show and then hide the widget after instantiation - because of the clever painting queue in Qt, it's unlikely to actually make it to the screen.
- Catch all mouse events in the viewport, work out which 'proxy' widget the cursor is over (if any), and then offset it to get the *relative* position for the 'real' hidden widget - this value will depend on what parent object the 'real' widget has, if any.  Then pass the event onto the 'real' widget before redrawing the widget framebuffer.

I should state that I also had to create a 'flagging' system to handle redraws nicely.  You don't want every widget event to trigger a widget FBO redraw, because there could many simultaneous events (don't just think about the mouse) - but you would only want one redraw.  So I created a system where if anything in the application could change anything in the viewport visually, then it would flag the viewport as 'dirty'.  Then setup a `QTimer` for however many fps you are aiming for (in my situation the scene could get very heavy, so I also timed how long a frame took and then used that value +10% as the timer delay for the next check, this way the system isn't bombarded when rendering gets laggy).  And then check the dirty status: if it's dirty, redraw; otherwise don't.  I found life got easier with two dirty flags, one for the 3D stuff and one for the 2D - but if you need to maintain a constant draw rate for the OpenGL drawing there's probably no need for two.

I imagine what I did wasn't the easiest way to do it, but it provides plenty of scope for tuning and profiling - which makes life easier in the long run.  All the answers are definitely not in this post, but hopefully it will get you on the way to a strategy.

Comment: so i have do do pretty much of it by hand. well, maybe good practice. thanks!